# Seeking Phrasal verb

Tags: phrasal-verbs

this is my first post on this site. So please bear with me. I am looking for a phrasal verb which is really common but I cant really remember it right now.

My phrase is :

"They stated they needed the change on their application and once it was done they [insert phrasal verb]..."

The one I am looking for is something like back off on their statement or maybe the said they actually did not need it.

I apologize to everybody in advance if my question is out of topic for this site. Phrasal verbs are actually hard to learn for a person who speaks English as a second tongue.

Comment: *They **backed off**?* ***Climbed down**?*

Comment: yeah. back off is one.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4qd7b3PDYAhUFRKwKHdR1B-cQFghDMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vocabulary.com%2Fdictionary%2Fback%2520off&usg=AOvVaw3_vxJnAWOXpjJpM1Rvwttf I am almost sure there was another one I heard like a million times and I still dont remember it

Comment: If they made a lot of fuss about needing that change, perhaps they ***calmed down*** once they'd got it. You need to give more detail about the exact nature of *how* their position/actions changed.

Comment: Can you describe a little more the feeling behind it? You could say "changed their mind", or "walked it back"...but I would also suggest changing the "...and once it was done..." to "...but once it was done", which signals a reversal a little better.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you start at thesaurus.com here: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/back%20off?s=t
It's actually quite good with phrasal verbs.